# Java Replace / Improve null check

Tags: java, null, option-type

I have a pseudo Java method where everything can be nullable:

```
private String prepareMessage(Scope scope) {
    if (scope != null) {
        if (scope.getPermission != null) {
            if (scope.getInfo != null) {
                return "Successful";
            } else {
                return "Missing field Info";
            }
        } else if (scope.getInfo() != null) {
            return "Permission field not provided";
        }
    }
    return "Permission and Info fields not provided";
}
```

How can I simplify this code to remove terrible looking null checks? Thanks !

Comment: What is your java version?

Comment: Bake them inside the `Scope` class? The code looks like validation, so you could also use bean validation.

Comment: @ernest_k I'm using java 8

Comment: getter methods of `Scope` class should return `Optional`

Comment: you can invert the null checks. Instead of checking `!= null` you check for `== null` and return the corresponding string.It would be more readable. See this question:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a helper method that suits you, an example:

```
public String notNullOrElse(Object o, String notNull, String isNull) {
    return null != o ? notNull : isNull;
}
```

Then you can change:

```
if (scope.getInfo != null) {
    return "Successful";
} else {
    return "Missing field Info";
}
```

to:

```
return notNullOrElse(scope.getInfo(), "Successfull", "Missing field Info");
```

However, sometimes those *horrible null checks* are unfortunately necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the idea ! Yes I agree.. just wanted to improve it a bit

Answer (score 1):

Tried refactoring the code. In most cases you can simplify If - else by re ordering the code flow. This makes getting code coverage easy.

```
private String prepareMessage(Scope scope) {
    if (scope == null) {
        return "Permission and Info fields not provided";
    }

    if (scope.getPermission != null && scope.getInfo != null) {
        return "Successful";
    } else {
        return scope.getPermission == null ? "Permission field not provided" : "Missing field Info";
    }

}
```

This doc beautifully explains code smells in if-else -> 
https://dzone.com/articles/code-smells-if-statements

Comment: The suggested refactoring changed the logic: the original code returned "Permission and Info fields are not provided" in case scope is not null, but both getters will return null. This version will just return "Permission field not provided". As the context is missing, it cannot be assessed whether this outcome may be also valid.

Comment: "_the original code returned "Permission and Info fields are not provided" in case scope is not null_"**you are wrong** please give brackets a look again.

Comment: sorry, but no! I suggest you run the code (your and the original one). The original code will return "Permission and Info fields not provided" in case scope is null OR when it is not null AND getPermission() and getInfo() will BOTH return null. That is different in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.7 introduces the class `java.util.Objects` ([this link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html) is from the Java 11 JavaDoc, but that should not matter here).

That class provides the methods `Objects.isNull()` and `Objects.nonNull()` that can be used as follows in your code:

```
import static java.util.Objects.*;
…
private String prepareMessage(Scope scope) {
    if (nonNull (scope)) {
        if (nonNull (scope.getPermission())) {
            if (nonNull (scope.getInfo())) {
                return "Successful";
            } else {
                return "Missing field Info";
            }
        } else if (nonNull (scope.getInfo()) {
            return "Permission field not provided";
        }
    }
    return "Permission and Info fields not provided";
}
```

Whether this looks better or not is a matter of taste, of course.

Alternative logic may look like this (for Java 11):

```
import static java.util.Objects.*;
…
private String prepareMessage( Scope scope ) 
{
    var messages = { "Successful", "Missing field Info", "Permission field not provided", "Permission and Info field not provided" };
    var index = 0;
    var retValue = messages [3]; // No scope at all

    if( nonNull( scope ) ) 
    {
        if( isNull( scope.getPermission() ) ) index += 2;
        if( isNull( scope.getInfo() ) ) index += 1;
        retValue = messages [index];
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

I do not want to say that this is really better in any way, it is just different. And it spares one null check …